# a proof that the borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by the collection of intervals $(-\infty,b]$ ,$b$ being a rational number

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Is my argument correct?

Let $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$,and let $\mathscr{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of intervals of the form $(-\infty,b]$ for which $b$ is a rational number. It is known that $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by the collection of half-open intervals of the form $(-\infty,r]$ where $r$ is a real number. It is clear that $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ contains $\mathscr{A}$. Now each interval $(-\infty,m]$ where $m$ is an irrational number is equal to the intersection of a collection of intervals of the form $(-\infty,q_n]$ where ${q_n}$ is a decreasing sequence of rational numbers approaching $m$ (such a sequence exists because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$). Since $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra it follows that $(-\infty,m]$ lies in $\mathscr{A}$ and hence $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a subcollection of $\mathscr{A}$, i.e. $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})=\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: Yes, looks fine.

Comment: @zhoraster thanks